# I'm having problems zooming into images that are in rows of an UITableView in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uiscrollview, zooming

I have a tableView inside a tabView, and my rows in the tableView contain images. I would like to zoom into the said images (I put them inside a scrollView and set the max/min zoom and I set ViewForZoomingInScrollView), but it seems I can't get the zoom to trigger because they are small images 50x56 or some other gesture/event is interfeiring. I use the same zoom code on another part of my app and it works perfectly. Has anyone come across the same or similar problem or knows a possible solution?

EDIT:

```
protected DocumentBaseCell()
        : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, new NSString("TableCell"))
    {

    ...

        documentImage = new UIImageView();
        documentImage.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("LaunchImage");
        documentImage.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
        documentImage.Layer.ZPosition = 0;

        imageScrollView = new UIScrollView();
        imageScrollView.ClipsToBounds = false;
        imageScrollView.ContentSize = new CGSize(50, 56);
        imageScrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 8f;
        imageScrollView.MinimumZoomScale = 1f;
        imageScrollView.Add(documentImage);
        imageScrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) =>
        {
            imageScrollView.ContentSize = new CGSize(documentImage.Frame.Width, documentImage.Frame.Height);
            return documentImage;
        };

        imageScrollView.DidZoom += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            //(sender as UIView).Layer.ZPosition = 2000;
        };

        imageScrollView.ZoomingEnded += (object sender, ZoomingEndedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            (sender as UIScrollView).SetZoomScale(0f, true);
            (sender as UIView).Layer.ZPosition = 0;
            this.Layer.ZPosition = 0;
        };
        ContentView.Add(imageScrollView);
    ...

    }
```

And this is the UpdateCell method:

```
internal virtual void UpdateCell(DocumentModel doc, string sup, string 
 docType, string user, string date, UIImage image)
    {
        if (image != null) 
        {
            this.documentImage.Image = image;
        }
        ...
    }
```

The Frame is set aswell:

```
public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        imageScrollView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 2, 50, 56);
        documentImage.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 50, 56);
    }
```

Comment: please show the relevant code

Comment: @Jason added the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give a `frame` to `imageScrollView` and `documentImage`, I download the official tableView sample project and add your code there, it zooms well.

```
public override void LayoutSubviews ()
{
    base.LayoutSubviews ();

    imageScrollView.Frame = new CGRect(ContentView.Bounds.Width - 233, 5, 133, 133);
    headingLabel.Frame = new CGRect(5, 4, ContentView.Bounds.Width - 63, 25);
    subheadingLabel.Frame = new CGRect(100, 18, 100, 20);
    imageView.Frame = imageScrollView.Bounds;

}
```

[image]

I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/ScrollViewInCell-iOS) and you can check it.

Comment: I updated my question, the frame is set. I think the problem is that the image is small (50x56). Can you try to make the images small and them try to zoom on them. The client wants those dimensions so I can't make the images bigger.

Comment: Yes, I tried with a small frame(50*56) and it also works. You can change the frame in my sample project and test again. Just make sure that the multitouch has triggered in that image as the image is small and it's harder to zoom in/out with two fingers.

Comment: @cymenx Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).